# android progress bar movement with audio

Tags: android, audio, progress

How can I make progress bar or progress dialog movement with audio in android

I am trying to design an audio player. I need help regarding the progress bar. I want the status of progress bar to change as the audio progresses. I want progress bar to pause as I press Pause button and start again as I press start button. Please help... 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1:

- Get audio duration with MediaPlayer.getDuration()

Step 2:

- Set ProgressBar progress max. value to value from step 1

Step 3:

- Update progress bar periodically from MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), while media playing using Handler. Check [here](http://developers.androidcn.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)

Remember to;

- Stop periodic update of step 3 at pauses and stops
- If you are going to add seek progress bar feature use MediaPlayer.seekTo(int msec) method, where msec is SeekBar.getProgress(), using SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangedListener

Good Luck!